# how to make doctrine generated column name to display in camel case in doctrine 2 symfony?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entities

I have an entity generated using doctrine in command line. It is as below -

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="COUNTRY_ID", type="string", length=2)
 */
private $cOUNTRYID;
```

In the database the column name is `COUNTRY_ID` and the SQL result will give assoc. array with `COUNTRY_ID` as key and its name as value.

My requirement is to have display name of SQL result to camel case. for example `COUNTRY_ID` should be `countryId`. Is there any config ready available in doctrine file to do this?.

Comment: Can you c/p your query?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *display name of SQL result*?

Comment: alright. I will explain in more details. My entity 'TFixed.php' and it has content as below.
`namespace RestBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * TFixedFees
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="RestBundle\Entity\TFixedRepository")
 */
class TFixed
{
    
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="USER_ID", type="integer")
     */
    private $uSERID;`

and when I do any SQL query, its result array will have `{'USER_ID':'67637673'}`. But I needed result to be in camel case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to implement a naming strategy to get camelCase autogenerated column names, as [explained in Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/namingstrategy.html).

Make a class to get camelCase name for your column names, <kbd>CamelCaseNamingStrategy.php</kbd>:

```
<?php
class CamelCaseNamingStrategy implements NamingStrategy
{
    public function classToTableName($className)
    {
        return 'cc_' . substr($className, strrpos($className, '\\') + 1);
    }
    public function propertyToColumnName($propertyName)
    {
        return $propertyName;
    }
    public function referenceColumnName()
    {
        return 'id';
    }
    public function joinColumnName($propertyName, $className = null)
    {
        return strtolower($propertyName) . ucwords($this->referenceColumnName());
    }
    public function joinTableName($sourceEntity, $targetEntity, $propertyName = null)
    {
        return strtolower($this->classToTableName($sourceEntity)) . ucwords($this->classToTableName($targetEntity));
    }
    public function joinKeyColumnName($entityName, $referencedColumnName = null)
    {
        return strtolower($this->classToTableName($entityName)) . ($referencedColumnName ?: ucwords($this->referenceColumnName()));
    }
}
```

Then register this new class as a service, and add it to your <kbd>config.yml</kbd>:

```
orm:
    #...
    entity_managers:
        default
            naming_strategy: my_bundle.camel_case_naming_strategy.default
```

Comment: I think OP generates his entities (the property names) from an existing database. Is there a possibility to set somthing like `columnNameToProperty` with a naming strategy?

Comment: @Wilt not sure about that, I still think it's about getting the camelCase column names in final. For your question, I think this would do the trick: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html (without decinding the naming strategy thought.)

Answer (score 2):

If you mean with display name the class property name, then you can do it like this:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="COUNTRY_ID", type="string", length=2)
 */
private $countryId;
```

The `name="COUNTRY_ID"`in your Column definition is the column name that doctrine uses to find it in the table (table column name).

The property name `$countryId` is the name of the property that Doctrine uses to bind the result of the query to. So if you want the class property to be in camel case you simply need to declare the property name camel cased.

Comment: Thank you. But the property names are all auto generated, Any idea how to set it to generate it in camelcase?.

Comment: @ManojKumar If you change the table name `COUNTRY_ID` to `country_id` it will become camel cased like you want. Is that a possibility or can you not change the table names?

Comment: Otherwise you could maybe read in [the Doctrine documentation on **Implementing a NamingStrategy**](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/namingstrategy.html) if you can find a solution there...